# Let ${a_n}$ be in $\ell_\infty$ . Prove that $f$ defined by $f({b_n})=\sum_\infty a_nb_n$ is a continuous real valued function on $\ell_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $a_n$ be in $l^\infty$ . Prove that $f$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
f(b_n) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_nb_n
\end{equation} is a continuous real valued function on $l^1$

---

My thoughts on the problem are that to show continuity, I must show that for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\vert b_n-x_n\vert< \delta$ implies 
$\vert a_nb_n-a_nx_n \vert< \epsilon$.

I'm thinking about factoring out the $a_n$, and letting my $\epsilon = \delta/a_n$.

Comment: Knowing that the sum of {an} doesn't necessarily converge, I am having trouble seeing how its continuous.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: @5xum I have now sir.

Comment: What does $f((b_n)-f((c_n)$ look like?

Answer (score 3):

$$\vert f(\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty)\vert = \vert \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n\vert\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \vert a_n\vert \vert b_n\vert\leq \Vert a_n\Vert_\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \vert b_n\vert=\Vert a_n\Vert_\infty\Vert b_n\Vert_1$$
Note that $f$ is linear so it is enough find $c>0$ such that $\vert f(b_n)\vert<c\Vert b_n\Vert$, put $c=\Vert a_n\Vert_\infty$

Comment: This only tells me that anbn resides in l^1

Comment: I have edited answer to have details that is needed

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator

Answer (score 0):

Let $(b_n)$ be a sequence in $l^1$, i.e. $\sum |b_n| < \infty$. Since $(a_n)$ is in $l^\infty$, there exists $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|a_n|<a$ for all $n$. Therefore, $|\sum a_nb_n|\leq\sum |a_nb_n|\leq a\sum |b_n|\leq \infty$ so your function is well-defined.

To show that it is continuous, take $\epsilon>0$ and $(b_n) \in l^1$. If $(c_n)\in l^1$ is such that $||(b_n)-(c_n)||=\sum |b_n-c_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{a}$, show that $f(c_n) \in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Shouldn't Sum (|anbn|) be less than na * Sum |bn| ?

Comment: Not really, $\sum |a_n||b_n| \leq \sum sup(|a_n|)|b_n|\leq \sum a |b_n|=a\sum |b_n|$.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the "norm" for space $\ell_1$.  If $b = (b_1, b_2, \cdots)$, then define
$$
\|b\|_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|
$$
Then prove: for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
if $\|b\|_1 < \delta$, then $f(b)<\epsilon$.  And of course you will have to use the definition of $f$ to find this $\delta$.

Strictly speaking, this shows continuity of $f$ at zero.  Then use that to prove continuity elsewhere.

**note**
It is confusing to write
$$
f(b_n) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_nb_n
$$
It is better to write
$$
f(b) = \sum_{n\geq 0} a_nb_n
$$
where $b = (a_1, b_2, \cdots)$